# Re-factoring regular expression to not include empty groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey so I have the following script which works:

It looks for the string `Phone: (##) ### ####`

```
$(function(){

    var regex = /(^|\W)Phone:($|\W)\(?([0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/g;
    var target = $('[data-hook="phone-number"]'); 
    var string = target.html();

    string = string.replace(regex, "><a href=\"tel:$3$5$6\">Phone: ($3) $5 $6</a>");

    target.html(string);
});
```

But as you may notice it is pretty rough (regex is not my strong point) I was wondering is there a way to ignore empty groups (`$1`, `$2`, `$4`) in this case.

So I can just use `$1`, `$2`, `$3` in an ideal world.

Also I could not figure out how to stop `(^|\W)` from ignoring the `>` symbol, hence why in my `replace` there is a trailing `>` is there a way to tell regex to shift / remove one number?

Comment: Do you want to always ignore those groups?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty specific so ignoring them is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `(?:)` which creates a non-capturing group:

```
/(?:^|\W)Phone:(?:$|\W)\(?(?:[0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/g
```

As [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973329/re-factoring-regular-expression-to-not-include-empty-groups/36973374?noredirect=1#comment61503671_36973374) said, you can also shorten it a bit:

```
/\bPhone:\s*\(?(?:[0-9]{2})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/g
```

Comment: While you're at it, change  `(?:^|\W)` to `\b` and `(?:$|\W)` to `\s*`.